# NPM Package Error- 'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: npm, postman, newman

I have installed the latest version of Newman (3.10.0) in my 64-Bit Win 10 Machine.

```
C:\Users\ABC>npm install -g newman
C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman -> C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin\newman.js
+ newman@3.10.0
added 195 packages in 57.852s
```

However, I am not able to use the newman and I am getting below error while accessing.

```
C:\Users\ABC>newman -h
'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added an environment variable for the **NODE_PATH** pointing to the newman directory `C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman`

but no luck. Could some one please help.

Comment: https://softans.com/apis-automation-via-newman-and-generate-html-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed after troubleshooting with the Node Application. A previous version of Node (32-bit) was installed in my machine and it was not completely removed after I did an uninstall. When I installed Node 64-Bit both entry was present in the environment variable and caused a conflict.

When I manually deleted both installation folder and the env variable the newman worked correcly.

Answer (score 6):

Adding in the **Path** variable  under Environment Variable solve the problem even if we **don't** add in **NODE_PATH**

C:\Users\ **yourusername** \AppData\Roaming\npm

After doing this **reopen** command prompt

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have installed **node**, **vc redist** and **newman** once (on clear windows 7 64 bit) and the issue is looks like related to wrong **newman** installation. Both **newman** and **node** should be installed from administrator session (not just with admin privileges). I have installed **newman** from regular user, system path setting are correct, but user environment was not set:

> path=C:\Users\gagarin\AppData\Roaming\npm

So I have copied

`C:\Users\<regular_user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

to `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm` and run `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd` from administrator session. After that **newman** command became work in admin session. Sadly it works in regular user session only if I type full path to newman like

> Blockquote

c:> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman run ....

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error and I have followed the below steps to troubleshoot it- 
1. Know what user is running jenkins, a simple way is Create a jenkins job and in its Build section run the command
whoami
2. If it shows System user, then do the following-
  2.a. Set C:\Users\I823285\AppData\Roaming\npm and C:\Users\I823285\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin in SYSTEM ENV. VARIABLES.
    b. Restart Jenkins by running CMD as ADMIN, and go to Jenkins installation folder, then enter jenkins.exe restart.
    c. Re-build the project
SUCCESSFUL!