# 'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, postman, newman

I have followed the following [Medium](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-configure-postman-newman-api-tests-in-azure-devops-or-tfs-and-publish-html-results-caf60a25c8b9) post on How to Configure postman / newman API tests in **Azure DevOps** or TFS and Publish HTML Results?

In my pipeline I have a task to install newman (Pass with command `install newman -g`) and a task to run api tests.(Fail - Error: 'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command.)

I have tried: A few solutions that can be found [here](https://community.postman.com/t/newman-is-not-a-reconized-as-a-internal-or-external-comman/1525) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381299/npm-package-error-newman-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) .

In my Environment variables I have:

1. npm\node_modules\newman\bin
2. \npm\node_modules\newman
3. %AppData%\npm

I did install newman using `npm install -g newman` and if I run `newman -v` I get a result of `5.2.2`.

My Azure task to run API request: `newman run Auth.postman_collection.json -e UserAuthEnvironmentVariables.postman_environment.json --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export Results\junitReport.xml`

'C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm' contains 3 newman files and `C:\Users\RRQA.RRIOMQAS01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman` also contains files and folders.

My node version is `v14.16.1` and npm version is `6.14.12`

When I edit environment variables I do restart my the server to make sure changes did take affect.

Any other suggestions what I might try to figure out the issue.?

Comment: did you figure out a nice way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you are running command line from azure and when you locally login to the system it might be running under different user identities (one in admin and another in your account) so sometimes what ever you have installed or set in environment variable won't be available in the admin identity login.

Make sure the installation is done for all users.  (Add path to system variable ) else:

install it as local module in the project directory as :

```
npm install newman newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

and use :

```
"./node_modules/.bin/newman" run
```

Comment: When installing a module using -g, the newman.cmd was available for use (locally) but not in my build process... When installing locally (ommitting -g), not .cmd file was installed, and I didn't realise you could just reference the module from the /.bin/{module} folder - this is very useful; thanks PDHide!