# Newman is not recognised as an internal or external command in Jenkins on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, postman

I'm using newman in Jenkins for executing the postman collection.

A brief background: I have installed node js in *C:\Program Files\nodejs* and newman was installed using globally so it got installed over here- *C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman*

About the environment variables:

1. *C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm* got added in the **User variables for the user** in the **Environment variables**
2. Also, I have appended *C:\Program Files\nodejs* in the **Path** variable of **User variables for user** and **System variables** both.

Now when I'm executing- "newman run Postman collection" OR C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman run postman collection, I'm getting the error as:

```
'C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong-
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51381299/4514250

Comment: @ParagSoni I have tried that also. But still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

add that directory that contains this file,  to your environment variable. it will be present in either of:

```
C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin
```

or

```
C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

or directly run it as :

```
 "C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman" run
```

, imagining that newman.cmd is in npm folder , use this command

Comment: This is how newman has exactly got installed 
```C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman``` and inside the newman folder, I have bin and the node_modules folder
So, you are saying about which bin folder?
```C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin ```or 
```C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\node_modules\.bin```?

Comment: I appended the ```C:\Users\waniijag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\node_modules\.bin```
 in the Path variable of System variables of environment variables.
It still did not work.

Comment: @Jagruuti see the updted answer

Comment: That is already added in both the Path variables of System variables and User variables of Environment. Is it that adding the path in both the variables will create confusion? If yes, then which one should I prefer? Or is the issue somewhere else?

Comment: @Jagruuti are you able to see that files ?

Comment: "C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman" run , imagining that  newman.cmd is in npm folder , use this command

Comment: @PDHide- Yes, I'm able to see those files.

Comment: Wow @PDHide, "C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman" run worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @PDHide- Can you update the main answer also so that I can mark it as an answer?